# I need to configure CORS in s3 bucket the code I have isn't a valid JSON

Tags: amazon-s3, gallery, bucket

I am trying to make a photo gallery from my s3 photo bucket. the next step in my process is to configure CORS but when I use the code provided I get an error. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong or how to change the code to valid JSON?

thanks for your help, its appreciated. Very new to this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)
The CORS configuration, written in JSON, defines a way for client web applications that are loaded in one domain to interact with resources in a different domain. Learn more
  
The CORS configuration must be written in valid JSON.
API response
Expected params.CORSConfiguration.CORSRules to be an Array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 27):

Copy paste example

```
[
 {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS has yet to update their document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

However, their explanation on using JSON policy still stands.

```
[
 {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
    // add more methods as required 
    // you may need PUT, POST, etc 
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    // for better security explicitly write your exact source url.
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
 }
]
```